# Default/original Multilevel list style no longer exists

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

This is not a question on how to edit a multi-level list style, modify, or delete it! There are many posts and solutions to that online.

My problem is that the usual multi-level list styles applied to style headings are gone. The ones that turn your heading styles into this:

```
1 Heading 1
2 Heading 1
2.1 Heading 2
2.2 Heading 2
2.2.1 Heading 3
2.2.2 Heading 3
2.2.2 Heading 3
```

and so on.

Normally I would:

1. Create a new blank document
2. Add some headings using styles, and then
3. Open the multi-level list dropdown, and select from the list library that has the 1, 1.1, 1.1.1 heading styles

However you can see from this screenshot, it doesn't exist:
[image: My multi-level list library options]

This is what I'm expecting to see (from support.microsoft.com) with my usual choice circled in red:

[image: Expected multi-level list library options]

Now, I can create a new multilevel list style, but this is very laborious, especially selecting all the correct "include level number", "link to style", "text indent", etc. etc. then I would have to save it to my normal template and so on.

I would like to know why I can't see this option.

Possible causes:

1. A broken `%AppData%/Microsoft/Templates/Normal.dotm` file
   -> I have deleted it and restarted word, and the behaviour is the same
2. Company policy / workspace templates
   -> in Word options > Advanced > File Locations, Workgroup templates is blank:

[image: File locations]

1. Broken Word. How do I fix this? There's no installer anymore! I'm using Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise: Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2207 Build 16.0.15427.20182) 64-bit
2. Anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled office however there were still office files lying around--enough to start Word etc. so I found the official [Office Uninstaller](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#officeversion=click-to-run_or_msi).

You need to determine if you have the *Click-to-Run or MSI* or *Microsoft Store* version. Instructions are on that page. Then download, install, and run.

It took about 1/2 hour, then I reinalled office and voila! My multilevel list style is back.

Answer (score -1):

Try running Office Repair. That feature is hit or miss, but if it works, great!

Susan H.